# Google Plus SignIn calls getting queued up

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to user google+ login in my backbone js app. The user flow is that

1. User clicks on a login button
2. This will open a bootstrap ( thttp://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ ) modal with the google+ sign in button ( along with facebook login, etc )
3. The user has to explicitly click on the g+ sign in button to log into my site.

To prevent automatic g+ SignIn what I do is display a custom g+ signin button and onclick I use the "gapi.signin.render" api with that custom signin button as the container. This works fine the very first time the signin button is clicked, but if the user logs out and tries to relogin nothing happens in the first click, but on the second click the g+ signin is triggered twice and increases by 1 everytime the user logs out and relogs in. And each time the g+ signin is triggered only on the second click. Note that my app is a single page app so there are no reloads between the logout and login. If I reload the site then again it works the first time and the issues is back for the subsequent sign ins.

Note: The modal( and its DOM ) I use for displaying the g+ Sign in buttons is removed after every successfull login and recreated everytime the user clicks on the main login button. I notice that after the successfull login the iframes created by g+ sign in button are still around and may be interfering when I recreate the modal again and invoke the "gapi.signin.render" api call.

The code I use is

In the backbone view, the render method has

```
render: function() {
        var thisV = this;
        _.defer(function(){
            gapi.signin.render('gSignIn', {
              'callback': thisV.gPlusLoginCB,
              'clientid': "clientID",
              'requestvisibleactions': "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
              'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
              'theme': 'dark',
              'cookiepolicy': "single_host_origin"
            });
        });
    }
```

And in the html template I have

```
<button id="gSignIn" class="btn gplogin">
      <i class="icon-google-plus"></i>Login
</button>
```

Any thoughts on how why the G+ Sign In calls are getting queued up or how to implement my scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out what was the issue?

Comment: No but to fix the issue I reload the full site on logout. That works for me as reload helps with few other items as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that so late. I just had the exact same issue.

When I moved the creation of the `options` object out of the function everything worked fine:

```
var options = {
                  'callback': thisV.gPlusLoginCB,
                  'clientid': "clientID",
                  'requestvisibleactions': "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                  'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                  'theme': 'dark',
                  'cookiepolicy': "single_host_origin"
                }

/**

/**

/**

    render: function() {
            var thisV = this;
            _.defer(function(){
                gapi.signin.render('gSignIn', options );
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any reason why you should be seeing the multiple authentication attempts.

Can you post a minimal code example where you're seeing this behaviour?

As a guess based on your description, are you mixing the custom rendering of the g-signin button with gapi.signin.render?  For example rendering a custom button with:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
    <!-- Custom button markup -->
  </span>
</span>
```

Then calling for example:

```
gapi.signin.render('signinButton', {
      //'callback': 'signinCallback',
      'clientid': 'CLIENT_ID',
      'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
      'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    });
  }
```

Comment: I posted the code in the original question. For now I fixed the issue by reloading the site on logout.